# noClassDefFoundError while loading jsp

Tags: jsp, struts

I am getting no class def error when trying to load a jsp page

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction
```

what could be the possible reason ?

i have got the struts jar in my web/lib folder

Comment: I hope you are using struts 1.0 version. Where you exactly got this error? Either in your action/jsp file?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the jar to lib folder will make it available during compile time. What a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the specific class is missing during runtime.

Check if you see a ClassNotFoundException below in stacktrace. If yes, then you are missing `Struts jar` in your classpath.